# a string that for every character in it, there exists all the characters which are alphabetically smaller than it before it

Tags: python, algorithm, string

How to check for a string that for every character in it, there exists all the characters which are alphabetically smaller than it before it  e.g aab  is correct while aacb is not, because the second case, we have 'c' but 'b' is not present before it. 
Also aac is not correct as it does not have 'b' before 'c'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pseudocode. Works for cases like `abac` too.

```
max = 'a' - 1  // character immediately before 'a'

for char in string
  if char > max + 1
    // bad string, stop algorithm
  end

  if char > max
    max = char
  end
end
```

The idea is that we need to check only that the character preceding the current one alphabetically has occurred before. If we have character `e` now and `d` has occurred before, then `c`, `b` and `a` did too.

Comment: People writing Ruby pseudocode on algorithm questions. Now I've really seen them all :)

Comment: @Geo That's funny: I did it unconsciously :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider this as a bad answer

```
import string

foo = string.printable[10:36]
a = 'aac'


for i in a:
    if i =='a':continue
    if a.rfind(foo[foo.rfind(i)-1])!=-1:continue
    else:print 'check_not cleared';break
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ALPHA = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

tests = [
         'aab','abac','aabaacaabade', # First 3 tests should eval True
         'ba','aac','aabbccddf'       # Last 3 test should eval False
         ]

def CheckString(test):
    alpha_counter = 0
    while test:
        if test[0] == ALPHA[alpha_counter]:
            test = test.replace(ALPHA[alpha_counter],'')
            alpha_counter+=1
        else:
            return False
    return True

for test in tests:
    print CheckString(test)


True
True
True
False
False
False
```

Given your criteria...

All you need to do is check the first letter to see if it passes your criteria... if it does, remove all occurrences of that letter from the string. And move onto the next letter. Your given criteria makes it easy because you just need to check alphabetically.

aabaacaabade

take the string above for example.

```
first letter 'a' passes criteria    [there are no letters before 'a']
remove all 'a's from string         remaining string: bcbde

first letter 'b' passes criteria    [there was an 'a' before the 'b']
remove all 'b's from string         remaining string: cde

first letter 'c' passes criteria    [there was an 'a' and a 'b' before the 'c']
remove all 'c's from string         remaining string: de

...
```

That should work if I understood your criteria correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the ascii encoding of the character.

```
mystr = "aab"
curr = ord(mystr[0])
for char in mystr[1:]:
    if ord(char) < curr:
        print "This character should not be here"
    if ord(char) > curr:
        curr = ord(char)
```

**Changes made to reflect user470379's suggestion:**

```
mystr = "aab"
curr = mystr[0]
for char in mystr[1:]:
    if char < curr:
        print "This character should not be here"
    if char > curr:
        curr = char
```

Comment: Why bother using `ord`? The characters will compare just fine by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I believe to understand your question correctly, and here is my attempt at answering it, if I have mis-understood please correct me.

The standard comparisons (<, <=, >, >=, ==, !=) apply to strings. These comparisons use the standard character-by-character comparison rules for ASCII or Unicode.  That being said, the greater and less than operators will compare strings using alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is very simple, for each char in the string, it should not less than its preceding, and it shouldn't larger than its preceding + 1.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? It simplifies the problem by first removing duplicate characters, then you only need to check the string is a prefix of the string containing all lowercase (ascii) letters.

```
import string

def uniq(s):
    last = None
    for c in s:
        if c != last: yield c
        last = c

def is_gapless_ascending(s):
    s = ''.join(uniq(s))
    return string.ascii_lowercase.startswith(s)
```